# Adding element into C++ std::map inserts only one key

Tags: c++, stdmap

I created a simple library program, where I store a map of Book objects and its quantity. I would like to add some books to the map to be further able to rent a book, etc.

The problem is that in my code, method called `createLib` inserts only one book object to the map. Why is that? How to solve this? What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Author
{
    public:
        string name;
        Author (){}
        Author(string n){name = n;}
};

class Book
{
    public:

        Author author;
        string title;
        static int id;

        Book (Author a, string t){author = a, title = t; id ++;}
};

int Book::id = 0;

struct comapare
{
    bool operator() (const Book& k1, const Book& k2)
    {
        return k2.id < k1.id;
    }
};

class Library
{
    public:
        map<Book, int, comapare> books;
        void createLib()
        {
            Author a1("Bruce Eckel");
            Book b1(a1, "Thinking in Java");
            Book b2(a1, "Thinking in C++");

            books.insert(std::make_pair(b1, 10));
            books.insert(std::make_pair(b2, 2));

            std::cout << books.size() << "\n";

        }
};

int main()
{
    Library l;
    l.createLib();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Author
{
public:
    string name;
    Author () {}
    Author(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
};

class Book
{
public:

    Author author;
    string title;
    static int id;
    int rid;

    Book (Author a, string t)
    {
        author = a, title = t;
        id ++, rid = id;
    }
};

int Book::id = 0;

struct comapare
{
    bool operator() (const Book& k1, const Book& k2)
    {
        return k2.rid < k1.rid;
    }
};

class Library
{
public:
    map<Book, int, comapare> books;
    void createLib()
    {
        Author a1("Bruce Eckel");
        Book b1(a1, "Thinking in Java");
        Book b2(a1, "Thinking in C++");

        books.insert(std::make_pair(b1, 10));
        books.insert(std::make_pair(b2, 2));

        std::cout << books.size() << "\n";
        for ( std::map<Book, int, comapare>::const_iterator iter = books.begin();
                iter != books.end(); ++iter )
            cout << iter->first.title << "\t\t" << iter->second << '\n';

    }
};

int main()
{
    Library l;
    l.createLib();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `id` is the same for all instances of the `Book` class.

You need *two* `id` members: One static member that you increase, and one non-static member that is the actual book id and is assigned to from the static id.

Comment: Thank you. You mean sth like this: http://pastie.org/private/f2aqjtqv0kz9m2xj9n4zeg? It does not work actually (or probably Im doing sth wrong)

Comment: Hmm, seems to work fine: http://pastie.org/private/xpeihzrvglhnapkcbnyba. Thank you for help!

Comment: @yak Almost, do e.g. `rid = id++;` instead of the comma expression you have nod. And the comparator needs to compare `rid` instead.